# When to use which with "есть"?

Tags: грамматика, значения, порядок-слов, разница, wording

Lets look at these 2 sentences:

1. у нас **есть** / We have.
2. что вы хотите **есть**? / What would you like to eat.

(In both of them the word "**есть**" is used differently).

I'm confused as for the use of  "**есть**" in both "ordering scenarios" where on one hand it refers to "having" (which I don't get since "у нас" should include having on its own same way that "у меня" on its own does without having to include this "есть" addition) and on the other hand it means to eat. Also Also how would the phrase in Russian "what do you HAVE to EAT" be written and if it includes "есть" 2 times? I am guessing it would be something like: "что есть у вас есть"? or "что у вас есть по есть"?

Maybe these last 2 sound grammatically horrific but I'm a newbie here, thanks a lot !

Comment: "Что у вас есть поесть?" ("поесть", no space) is quite a smooth-sounding phrase in Russian.

Comment: what does this picture have to do with the question? why not Hugo Chavez or Fidel? is this an attempt to win favor with Russian users?

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions. Russian has lots of good very to the point proverbs, one of which is "какой привет, такой ответ", make your post political, provokative or simply extremely outlandish expect a response in kind, worth reading the text in my profile... your rejoinder doesn't come across as polite at all, which is regrettable for one asking for help

Comment: Please do not put the picture of Putin in the question again!

Comment: Are you an idiot? Please DON'T! Stop doing this.

Comment: I marked all your questions for moderators.

Comment: Great ! Feel good about yourself yet? Let them know you are treating people in "idiot" terms to see how profesional you sound when you snitch around tryin to get me banned. Dont worry, I'll make sure Moderators know about u too. ;)

Comment: it's sad that of all heroes which exist in Russian culture this user has chosen a villain, the most obvious personality one could imagine without looking past flashing news headlines... **if he's so eager to attach images to his posts no matter what, images of non-controversial figures and symbols would be more welcome**

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка *images of non-controversial figures and symbols would be more welcome* - No, images (or any other information) irrelevant for the question are *not*  welcome. It does not matter if it's vodka, martreshka, balalayaka, bear, Putin or whatever - it's all just a stupid kiddish offtop.

Comment: @seven-phases-max i tend to agree, but since we don't really have the tools to stop this once and for all, that would be the least evil so to speak, a compromise

Comment: @nicolasns96 Please stop attaching completely unrelated images to the posts.

Comment: @dimitry I will continue doing it as I find suitable for my questions and posts, since is in my very own rights to do it. As long as I am not posting any sort of violent, sexually explicit or graphic content in any way. There is no argument for intercepting on an image that DOES INDEED RELATE TO RUSSIAN CULTURE. I am not directly attacking or offending anyone, if you don't think it is "professional" then leave the community, this is a free forum platform for self expression. So really buddy, go an X urself if you think you can interfere with my means of expression.

Comment: @nicolasns96 *this is a free forum platform for self expression* - No, SE is *not* a forum or a blog-like platform or anything like this. Thus you're *not* free to write *anything you want* in you Q. SE Q/A items are *never* meant for a selfexpression or a conversation of any kind. Just start with https://stackexchange.com/tour to find more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These two "есть" are homonyms. Есть like "to eat " and есть like "to own, possess,have". For choosing just consider the context.

In case of possession we can use the verb or leave it out. And in most cases we don't use the verb. But sometimes we use it for emphasis or you can't do without it (in questions mostly).

> У нас (есть) большие возможности.У него много друзей. У вас есть конверты?– Да, есть. Есть ли какие‐нибудь новости о нем?

As for есть --to eat, we often say that sentence.

> У нас есть что‐нибудь поесть?

Besides there's есть meaning "exists"

> Есть многое на свете,  друг Горацио,что и не снилось нашим мудрецам.